# When is it possible to extend a continuous function defined on a dense set on X to all the space X.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X $ and $Y $ be topological spaces, $D \subseteq X $ a dense set of $X $ and  $f: D \rightarrow Y$ a continuous function. My question  is:  Is  it  always  possible to define $g:X \rightarrow Y $ such  that  g  is continuous and  $g (x) = f (x) $ for  all $x \in D $?

Comment: In some special cases, but not usually. E.g. when $X=\beta D$, the Cech-Stone compactification of $D$ and $Y$ is compact Hausdorff. Or when $X$ and $Y$ are complete metric spaces and $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$.

Comment: If $D=\omega$ and $X=\omega+1$, then $f$ is a sequence, and it can be continuously extended to $X$ iff that sequence converges.

Comment: ...and if $D=\Bbb Q$ the rationals, and $X=\Bbb R$, the reals then for every sequence of rationals converging to an irrational the function must have a limit, and for different sequences of rationals converging to the same irrational, the function limits must be the same. In particular, if $f(r)=0$ for $r<\pi$ and $f(r)=1$ for $r>\pi, r\in\Bbb Q$ this $f$ is a simplest example that cannot be extended.

Comment: You can if $X$ is metric and $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider the function $f:\mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto -1$ if $x < \sqrt 2$ and $x \mapsto 1$ if $x>\sqrt 2$.

It can be seen to not extend to $\mathbb R$.

This is because extension of a map $D \rightarrow Y$ from a dense subset of $X$ to the whole space is unique if $Y$ is hausdorff. Thus we can deduce that if $f':\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an extension of $f$, $f'$ would have to be locally constant except at $\sqrt 2$.

Thus we can deduce that $f'$ is constant on the two connected components of $\mathbb R - \{\sqrt 2\}$.

Now we divide the problem into a few cases.

Assume that $f'(\sqrt2)=1$. Then $f^{-1}((1- \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)) = [\sqrt(2), \inf)$ and if we  make a similar argument for the case $f'(\sqrt 2) = -1$ we deduce that $f'(\sqrt 2) \neq -1$ and $f'(\sqrt 2) \neq 1$ since preimages of open sets don't yield open sets under these assumptions.

Now working under the assumption that $f'(\sqrt 2) \neq 1 $ nor $ -1 $ consider the preimage of the set $(f'(\sqrt 2)-\epsilon, f'(\sqrt 2) + \epsilon)$ which we know has to be equal to $\{\sqrt 2\}$ which is not open. This covers all posibilities for what $f'(\sqrt 2)$ may equal and none of them make $f'$ continuous. Thus there is no extension of $f$ to $\mathbb R$.